# "field does not exist"-error on submitting form

Tags: symfony

I have this code in my "new-action" of the Challenge-controller. It throws me the error "field player_one does not exist" when I submit my Challenge-form.

```
if ($form->isValid()) 
{    
    foreach($form->get('teams') as $team_form) 
    {
        $player_one = $team_form->get('player_one')->getData();  
        $player_two = $team_form->get('player_two')->getData();

        $user_one = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TennisconnectUserBundle:User')->findOneByUsername($player_one);
        $user_two = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TennisconnectUserBundle:User')->findOneByUsername($player_two);

        // Add user(s) to the two teams
        foreach($challenge->getTeams() as $i => $team)
        {
            // First team
            if($i == 0)
            {
                if($user_one)
                {
                    $team->addUser($user_one);                                
                } elseif($user_two)
                {
                    $team->addUser($user_two);
                }
            } 
            // Second team
            elseif($i == 1)
            {
                if($user_one)
                {
                    $team->addUser($user_one);                                
                } elseif($user_two)
                {
                    $team->addUser($user_two);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($challenge);
    $em->flush();               

    return $this->render('TennisconnectDashboardBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'user' => $user));
}
```

But when I debug "$player_one", it gives me the correct value from the textbox:

```
$player_one = $team_form->get('player_one')->getData();
die($player_one);
```

Comment: The code you posted does not seem relevant to the question you are asking. The code you posted would run if the form validation succeeded, which you're saying it is not. We need to see what's going on inside the form's isValid() method. As well as sample $_POST data submitted via said form.

Comment: I think it is valid because when I type 'die("test")' inside the 'if(isValid())' and then submit the form, it dies and shows the 'test' message

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. 
When I did this, it gave me 3 as a result whilst I was only adding 2 team forms to the challenge form.

```
die(count($form->get('teams')));
```

I had to remove the csrf token like this

```
$form->get('teams')->remove('_token');
```